# How many Space Exploration Members are active in the space industry?

Tags: discussion, users

This question really has very little relevance, and truly is only being asked from my own curiosity but;

How many Space Exploration Stack Exchange members are active in the space industry?

To clarify; by active in the industry I mean your typical employment is related to the space industry directly. Academia *doesn't* count. The only downside of this question is I can't see a way any single user could answer it!

Comment: Sorry to comment on a quesion with another question, does Stack Exchange provide any functionality to do a survey? e.g. Educator/ Academic research/ Student/ Manager/ Sales/ Mission related engineering/ Applications developer.

Comment: No idea. Would be nice though!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can tell you from my experience with our members that we have quite many field professionals here, from those that actually landed hardware on Mars,  to those working for large space launch providers and in space systems integration, analytics and space policy, space historians,... That isn't really a coincidence as we actively work in promoting our site to relevant expert communities (see e.g. [this thread](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/667/49) as an example of that), but unfortunately, I'm not at liberty to disclose which individuals that are or where they work, unless they're comfortable in sharing that by themselves (site policy). You might however recognize some of the names in our [list of members](https://space.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) by yourself, though [Elon Musk](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/12051/elon-musk) that ain't.

Answer (score 24):

I'm a retired shuttle engineer with 30 years experience in mission ops at Johnson Space Center.  So, "formerly active", to answer your question directly.

Answer (score 23):

Spent a career in high performance military aviation and served in NASA's Astronaut Corp for eight years.  Flew in Space once.

Answer (score 17):

I am a Software Engineer active within the industry. I'm not sure what you mean by *"your typical employment is related to the space industry directly"*, but I work in support of such programs.

Answer (score 16):

I work on rocket turbomachinery at the German aerospace agency DLR.

Answer (score 6):

I worked as a contract aerospace engineer at Johnson Space Center for about ten years. I was lead developer of, and subject-matter-expert for, the Rendezvous and Proximity Operations Program (RPOP) 8, and was a fly on the wall during a lot of Commercial Crew Development rendezvous conversations.

Answer (score 5):

I was an Operations Controller at MSFC POIC running payload ops (science experiments) for the ISS for 3 years.

Basically if anything went wrong during a science experiment, my job was to troubleshoot and get the crew back on the timeline as scheduled. I was also responsible for crew safety during payload ops.

Answer (score 5):

I work for ESA as a software engineer. Ground segment software for Earth observation missions.